# How does std::string assign operator work?

Tags: c++

I was trying to figure out how the following statement works in C++:

```
std::string a = "simple_text";
```

Is the "a" object first initialized with empty text and then the "simple_text" is assigned to it or is the "a" object initialized with the "simple_text" straight away?

I would be grateful for an answer.

Comment: There's no assignment in this code. This is initialization, and it invokes `std::string::string(const char *)` (among others), i. e. a constructor, and not `std::string::operator=`. How it is implemented is irrelevant.

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a13f1d093e8440e7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if the constructor is not defined with the keyword `explicit`, then the compiler can adapt

```
std::string a = "simple_text";
```

to

```
std::string a = std::string("simple_text");
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case it is not the `=` operator but rather the `CCTOR`. Since `a` isn't constructed yet, it has to be constructed.

You can experience that in the following example:

```
class Foo{
    int bar;
public:
    Foo(int anInt): bar(anInt){
        std::cout << "CTOR called\n";
    }
    Foo(Foo& aFoo){
        this->bar = aFoo.bar;
        std::cout << "CCTOR called\n";
    }
    Foo& operator=(Foo& aFoo){
        this->bar = aFoo.bar;
        std::cout << "operator = called\n";
        return *this;
    }

};

int main(){
    Foo aFoo(5);
    Foo bFoo = aFoo; // since bFoo is not instantiated yet, the CCTOR constructs it.
    return 0;
}
```

The output will be

```
CTOR called
CCTOR called
```

Answer (score 1):

This statement

```
std::string a = "simple_text";
```

is not copy assignment operator. It is a definition of an object so there is used a constructor.

This statement is equivalent to

```
std::string a = std::string( "simple_text" );
```

At first a temporary object is created std::string( "simple_text" ); with using constructor with parameter `const char *` and then this object is moved into a by using the move constructor.

However the C++ Standard allows to eliminate the call of the move constructor. So definition

```
std::string a = "simple_text";
```

will be equivalent simply to

```
std::string a( "simple_text" );
```